# setMouseTracking not working pyqt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

So i'm making a game in Pyqt5, and need to get the mouse position so I implemented something like this (only include relevant part of the code):

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        MainWindow.resize(774, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.setMouseTracking(True)


    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        print(event.x(), event.y())
```

the class inherits from a .ui loaded file, and for now I just print the position, but it only fires up when the a mouse button is pressed.

**Edit**
I changed the code so it only has the essential, I orriginaly used a ui file from Qtdesigner

Comment: what are `Window[0]`, `Window[1]`?

Comment: The code must be relevant, minimal and **verifiable**.